# Summarize and remove any rows which has a blank total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have written a DAX code which returns names of individuals with a count of how many customers they own, however what I need to do is only retrieve the names or essentially filter out the names who have a blank total, how would I go about this as I have tried everything

```
summarizedCAM = 
    SUMMARIZE (
            d_cam,
            d_cam[name],
            "Total", DISTINCTCOUNT(ftm[p_key])
     
   )
```

Current Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
summarizedCAM = 
FILTER(
    SUMMARIZE (
            d_cam,
            d_cam[name],
            "Total", DISTINCTCOUNT(ftm[p_key])
    
   )
   ,ISBLANK([Total])=FALSE()
)
```

Comment: is this a measure ? calculated column ? or a calculated table ? )))

Comment: it's a calculated table

Comment: @Mik I hate when the var table and columns cannot be used afterwards in the code...

Comment: @jcoke i know (he also knows) but he should have mentioned in his answer ))) i am teasing Mik )))

Comment: @UmutK, may be it's not needed

Comment: @Mik it would make codes easier i believe...

Answer (score 2):

try like this :

Modelling --> New Table

```
summarizedCAM =
VAR _tbl =
    SUMMARIZE ( d_cam, d_cam[name], "Total", DISTINCTCOUNT ( ftm[p_key] ) )
RETURN
    FILTER ( _tbl, [Total] > 0 )
```

Comment: I tried that first, it says DISTINCTCOUNT function only accepts a column reference as an argument

Comment: @jcoke sorry i didnt have time to check, i edited, please try now

Comment: That returned an error saying The TRUE/FALSE expression does not specify a column

Comment: @jcoke now tested and working...